# How Do I Run 2 npm Commands In My Azure WebApp?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

When running my web app I also run json-server to mock the API.

This means that I have 2 sets of commands:

```
//Start json-server
cd mock-server
npm start
//Start web-app
cd ../web-app
npm start
```

I want to host this in Azure so that I have a demo with no external dependencies that I can use to show to people.

However, when I create a WebApp resource in Azure and try to deploy the project it only allows me to run a single command to start it.

How do I run both json-server and my app in Azure?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: Not yet. I am now running into other problems where Azure is failing to deploy the web app so I can't test this yet. https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9458

Answer (score 0):

**Newest**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "Start json-server command start",
    "multiplestart": "(cd ../web-app && npm run start) & npm run start"
}
```

I will share four ways to run multiple Node.js commands or NPM scripts at once.

[Solutions To Run Multiple Node.js or NPM Commands Simultaneously](https://itnext.io/4-solutions-to-run-multiple-node-js-or-npm-commands-simultaneously-9edaa6215a93)

Comment: Link only answers aren't great. Which of those is most appropriate? The first one doesn't work in Azure.

Comment: What are the startup commands of these two projects separately?